# Can .NET Core 2.0 speak OData v2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, sapui5

The stable version of the OData Nuget Package for .NET Core 2.x (Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData) has been released in mid 2018. But it only supports OData v4, not older versions of OData.

We need to speak OData v2 to communicate with SAPUI5. For .NET Framework there are both versions available: a Nuget Package for OData v1 to 3 and another one for v4.

Is there any way to speak OData v2 with .NET Core 2.x?

**Update**

In the long run we need to speak OData v2 both ways:

1. Create OData v2 endpoints in .NET Core (to communicate with SAPUI5 frontends)
2. Create an OData v2 client with .NET Core (to communicate with SAP Netweaver Gateway)

Right now 1. has a much higher focus though, but 2. will come soon.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer, but ...  what have you tried?

Comment: Are you asking how to *create* 2.0 endpoints or how to *call* 2.0 endpoints? That package allows the creation of OData services.

Comment: @Neil: I have tried for about two weeks to use the v4 Nugets in .NET Framework against SAPUI5 (and I documented this in answers on Stackoverflow). There is no point in going through that PITA again with .NET Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I updated my question: Endpoints are what we are looking for right now. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the exact same problem, because of our openUI5 frontend.

Comment: @t2t: No, unfortunately not. To solve the problem we will now start to use the OData Model v4 of SAPUI5 and I honestly hope that it is mature enough to fully support our project. I'm afraid we are taking a big risk.

Comment: @Jpsy did that work out? its a real crap that SAP still prefers v2.

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer: v4 is the only way with Core. We did not succeed in our trials to use v2. Maybe this helps: https://blogs.sap.com/2021/02/05/is-it-time-to-switch-to-odata-v4/

Answer (score 2):

Although the page for it doesn't say it, a cursory glance at the .nupkg file for Microsoft.Data.OData, version 5.8.4 seem to indicate that it targets both .NET 4.0 and .NET Standard 1.1. .NET Standard 1.1 is implemented by .NET Core versions starting 1.0, so it should be fine.

I guess you should just try to install it in your project and see if it builds.

Comment: Will check that soon and report. Thanks @EtiennnedeMartel.

Comment: @EtiennnedeMartel: I tried to implement your solution but there are so many obstacles that I'm giving up. The most serious road block is that I do not find a way to migrate all OData config options from .NET Framework's WebApiConfig.cs structure to the Startup.cs structure of .NET Core. I found migration tutorials that mention a Microsoft WebApiCompatShim library. But that looks like another dead end road that will take many days to explore. Without a working example I unfortunately cannot mark this answer as a solution. But thanks again for you trying to help.